# Visual Studio Professional 2013 and .NET Framework 4.6.1

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013, windows-7

I've got a copy of Visual Studio Professional 2013, trying to load up a project targeting .NET Framework version 4.6.1. I have installed the actual framework, the targeting pack, and the clickonce bootstrapper, all from Microsoft directly.

For whatever reason, the project can't sense that 4.6.1 is installed, and keeps asking me to download it (which, to my frustration, just leads to microsoft.com/en-us), or to re-target to 4.5, the version my machine apparently believes is the most current.

I'm not sure how to get around this, but it seems to be a known issue for machines running OS versions prior to Windows 8.1. I have no issues on my Windows 10 device running 2015 Community (different version, I know).

Either way, need to resolve this on the Win 7 machine.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, though I don't know why it works now. In this order, I re-installed .NET Framework 4.6.1, restarted, re-installed Targeting Pack (4.6.1), restarted, and then re-installed the ClickOnce bootstrapper.

Should help that I got the files from [here](http://getdotnet.azurewebsites.net/target-dotnet-platforms.html#)

Hope that helps!